# Adding a regression line from specific locations in a plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, linear-regression

I am trying to mimic Crow-AMSAA analysis in R; especially trying to generate Figure 1 in Page 7 of the [document](http://www.barringer1.com/pdf/Barringer-Kuwait-1.pdf). I have compiled the data in R as ::

```
aa <- data.frame(Time = c(17, 21, 164, 253.5, 7902, 12363.5, 17059, 19945.5, 25671), 
            Failures = 1:9)
```

Time in the data is the cumulative time. I generated different groups, such as `all data`, `first four` and `last five`.

```
bb <- aa[1:4,]
cc <- aa[(nrow(aa)-5):nrow(aa), ]
# Add groups to the data
aa$Groups <- c("All")
bb$Groups <- c("First_Four")
cc$Groups <- c("Last_Five")
# Combine data 
fin_df <- rbind(aa,bb,cc)
```

I tried to generate the Figure using `ggplot2` as

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(fin.df) +  geom_smooth(aes(Time, Failures,  group = Groups, colour = Groups), 
                                   method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

or alternatively I also tried the `stat_ecdf` function, without success.

```
p <- ggplot(aa, aes(Time, Failures,  group = Groups, colour = Groups)) +  
     stat_ecdf()
```

I also tried base graphics as ::

```
plot(aa$Failures, aa$Time, col = 1)
fit <- lm( aa$Time ~ aa$Failures )
print(fit)
abline(fit$coefficients[[1]], fit$coefficients[[2]], col = 1)

par(new = TRUE)

plot(aa$Failures[1:4], aa$Time[1:4], col = 2)
fit <- lm( aa$Time[1:4] ~ aa$Failures[1:4] )
print(fit)
abline(fit$coefficients[[1]], fit$coefficients[[2]], col = 2 )


par(new = TRUE)

plot(aa$Failures[5:9], aa$Time[5:9], col = 3)
fit <- lm( aa$Time[5:9] ~ aa$Failures[5:9] )
print(fit)
abline(fit$coefficients[[1]], fit$coefficients[[2]], col = 3 )
```

The final output I want is the Figure below[image]

Comment: I don't see any effort on your part to read the methods they used. Where is your effort to calculate the CDF or to set the x-axis as log10 survivals?